# PHP - Check date is in the past but exclude todays date

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm using the following function to check whether the date is in the past, but I want to exclude today’s date from it as it returns true for today's date also.

For example, if I pass today's date 2018-03-15, it returns true when it shouldn't.

```
function is_date_in_past($date):bool
{
   return !empty($date) && (strtotime($date) < time());
}
```

Can anybody please help me with this, that how to exclude today's date from being recognised as past date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. They are easier to use than the old [date & time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) and the code is more clear.

Comment: raw time() represents exactly now, including hours, minutes, seconds etc. and therefore the start of today (as represented by your date string, which has no time component and therefore defaults to midnight) is before it in terms of time (not just date). Instead compare to the start of today, removing the time element.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. They are easier to use than the old [date & time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) and the code is more clear.

```
function is_date_in_past($date) {
    return new DateTime($date) < new DateTime("today");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use old date/time functions, you can do like that:

```
 function is_date_in_past(string $date) :bool
 {
     return !empty($date) && strtotime($date) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
 }
```

but better to consider to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/49305230/9254020 variant